# Stopped displaying rep gains

Tags: bug, ios-app

Hi the app stopped showing rep increases and now is just showing badges. Yesterday it showed both rep and badges earned.

[image]

- App Version: 1.4.0
- Device: iPhone7,1
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Comment: Wow... I won this contest by a minute... and I have images :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270510/rep-point-changes-arent-showing-in-ios-app-achievements-tab